# Convergence rate of the inverse covariance matrix

Tags: references, convergence, covariance-matrix

I am trying to find results regarding the convergence rate of the inverse covariance matrix in the case where the number of observations $n$ is larger than the number of dimensions $p$.

Assume that $X \in R^p$ and $Var(X) = \Sigma$.

Then $\hat{\Sigma} = \frac{X'X}{n-1}$, $n$ being the number of observations. Are there results regarding the convergence rate of $\hat{\Sigma}^{-1}$ to $\Sigma^{-1}$ as $n$ grows?

Comment: Every given element of the $X$ appearing in $\hat{\Sigma}$ is to be replaced with the difference of the element and the sample average.

Comment: $X$ is usually a sample. Why would $X \in \mathbb{R}^p$? Do you mean to say that $X$ is a $n \times p$ matrix of real values?

Comment: Are you asking about the *covariance matrix* or about the matrix $\hat \Sigma,$ which almost surely is *not* the covariance matrix of the samples?